ErrorException : Trying to access array offset on value of type null
I'am getting this error. But, i don't know how to solve.
Trying to access array offset on value of type null

PHP Version
8.0.11

Controller.php file
$set_halaman_depan = $this->request->getVar('set_halaman_depan');
$set_halaman_kontak = $this->request->getVar('set_halaman_kontak');

$konfigurasi_name = 'set_halaman_depan';
$dataGet = konfigurasi_get($konfigurasi_name);
$page_id_depan = '';
if ($set_halaman_depan == '1') {
    $page_id_depan = $page_id;
}
if ($dataGet['konfigurasi_value'] == $page_id && $set_halaman_depan != '1') {//Trying to access array offset on value of type null
    $page_id_depan = '';
}
$dataSet = [
    'konfigurasi_value' => $page_id_depan
];
konfigurasi_set($konfigurasi_name, $dataSet);

Helpers.php file
function konfigurasi_get($konfigurasi_name)
{
    $model = new App\Models\KonfigurasiModel();
    $filter = [
        'konfigurasi_name' => $konfigurasi_name
    ];
    $data = $model->getData($filter);
    return $data;
}

function konfigurasi_set($konfigurasi_name, $data_baru)
{
    $model = new App\Models\KonfigurasiModel();
    $dataGet = konfigurasi_get($konfigurasi_name);
    $dataUpdate = [
        'id' => $dataGet['id'],
        'konfigurasi_name' => $konfigurasi_name,
        'konfigurasi_value' => $data_baru['konfigurasi_value']
    ];
    $model->updateData($dataUpdate);
}

I use codeigniter php framework Ver. 4.4.6 to create this project.

"I don't know how to solve" The first obvious step is to look at the line that throws the error.
